# Making an array out of multiple arrays

Tags: python, excel

I want to make a new array out of different numbers from each array. This is an example:

```
import numpy as np


a=[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
b=[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
v=[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
d=[]

for c in range (0,2):
    d.append([])
    for s in range (0,10):
        d[c] =np.concatenate((a[c][s],b[c][s],v[c][s]))

print(d)
```

when I print 'd', it gives me a TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Is this due to the concatenante function? or can I use stack?

I want the outcome to be something like:

```
d[0][1]= [-1,-1,-1]
```

and

```
d[1][1]=[1,1,1]
```

having the nth term from each array. d[0][0] is indexing to an excel file and a row. that's why I want this format.

Comment: That's because you overwrite the `c` array with a loop variable `c`.

Comment: ...and that's exactly the reason you are supposed to extract a minimal example before posting here. BTW: There are formatting guidelines for Python code (PEP 8, I think), use those. It makes it easier for other Python programmers to read and understand your code.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What was wrong with my question? I put my code and my thoughts, an example of what I wanted the outcome to be, and my error....
or is it just my coding?

Comment: It's the "minimal but complete" example that's missing. You are supposed to extract that first, because it forces you to focus on the issue and it avoids asking questions about simple glitches like the one you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for your error is that you're overwriting the `c` list with a loop variable of the same name -

```
for c in range (0,2):
    ...
```

So, `c` is an `int`, and `c[c][s]` is obviously invalid with python.

---

It seems you're looking for `dstack` -

```
d = np.dstack((a, b, c))

d
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [ -1,  -1,  -1],
        [ -2,  -2,  -2],
        [ -3,  -3,  -3],
        [ -4,  -4,  -4],
        [ -5,  -5,  -5],
        [ -6,  -6,  -6],
        [ -7,  -7,  -7],
        [ -8,  -8,  -8],
        [ -9,  -9,  -9],
        [-10, -10, -10]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        [  3,   3,   3],
        [  4,   4,   4],
        [  5,   5,   5],
        [  6,   6,   6],
        [  7,   7,   7],
        [  8,   8,   8],
        [  9,   9,   9],
        [ 10,  10,  10]]])

v[0][1]
array([-1, -1, -1])

v[1][1]
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You have an array with the same name as the loop variable, so you overwrite the array c each time it loops through.

Comment: I saw you change your answer.

Comment: Cause I realized mine was wrong and I can't delete it afterwards so might as well make it correct. :)

Comment: Well, you can delete your answer, using the [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158308/making-an-array-out-of-multiple-arrays/48158364#) button.

Comment: Ah, because you aren't a registered user.